# Several arrays emptys

Tags: javascript

I have 3 arrays as this:

```
tabNoms = new Array("Jean", "Maximilien", "Brigitte", "Sonia", "Jean-Pierre", "Sandra");
tabMaximum = new Array();
tabMinimum = new Array();
```

The goal is to recuperate each elements from array tabNoms which must have 4 letters maximum and the put in tabMaximum.

Here is my algorithm but it doesn't works

```js
tabNoms = new Array("Jean", "Maximilien", "Brigitte", "Sonia", "Jean-Pierre", "Sandra");
tabMaximum = new Array();
tabMinimum = new Array();
 function main()
 {
  for(var i = 0; i<tabNoms.length; i++){
   if(tabNoms[i] < 4){
    tabMaximum.push(tabNoms[i]);
   }
  }
 document.write("Maximum 4 letters : " + tabMaximum);
}
```

Do you an idea ? Please ? 
Thanks

Comment: `if(tabNoms[i] < 4){` remember that `tabNoms[i]` will be a name, so you would be doing something like `"Jean" < 4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the length of the string ([`String#length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length)).

```js
function main() {
    for (var i = 0; i < tabNoms.length; i++) {
        if (tabNoms[i].length <= 4) {
            tabMaximum.push(tabNoms[i]);
        }
    }
    document.write("Maximum 4 letters : " + tabMaximum);
}

var tabNoms = ["Jean", "Maximilien", "Brigitte", "Sonia", "Jean-Pierre", "Sandra"],
    tabMaximum = [],
    tabMinimum = [];

main();
```

Comment: thaaaaanksss a lottt !! :-)

Answer (score 2):

You have to correct you `if condition`. Change

```
if(tabNoms[i] < 4){
```

To this

```
if(tabNoms[i].length <= 4){
```

**Because here you have to check the `length` of `string`**

```js
tabNoms = new Array("Jean", "Maximilien", "Brigitte", "Sonia", "Jean-Pierre", "Sandra");
tabMaximum = new Array();
tabMinimum = new Array();



function main()
 {
   for(var i = 0; i<tabNoms.length; i++){
    if(tabNoms[i].length <= 4){
          tabMaximum.push(tabNoms[i]);
     }
   }
 console.log("Maximum 4 letters : " + tabMaximum);
}
main();

var result=tabNoms.filter(obj => obj.length <= 4);
console.log(result);
```

2. You can also use [**`Array.propotype.filter()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

   ```
   var result=tabNoms.filter(obj => obj.length <= 4);
   console.log(result);
   ```

```js
tabNoms = new Array("Jean", "Maximilien", "Brigitte", "Sonia", "Jean-Pierre", "Sandra");
var result = tabNoms.filter(obj => obj.length <= 4);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
tabNoms = new Array("Jean", "Maximilien", "Brigitte", "Sonia", "Jean-Pierre", "Sandra");
tabMaximum = new Array();
  
function main(){
  tabMaximum = tabNoms.filter(item => item.length <= 4);
  console.log(tabMaximum)
  document.write("Maximum 4 letters : " + tabMaximum);
}

main()
```